# How to debug "error: class X is public, should be declared in a file named Y" in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class PhraseOMatic {
    public void main (String[] args) {
        String [] wordListOne = {"24/7","multitier","Akshay","Aalok","teslaBoys","Team"};

        String[] wordListTwo = {"empowered","positivity","money","foucused","welth","strenth"};

        String[] wordListThree = {"ok","dear","priorityies","love","Dreams","sapne"};

        int oneLength = wordListOne.length;
        int twoLength = wordListTwo.length;
        int threeLength = wordListThree.length;

        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
        int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);
        int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * threeLength);

        String phrase = wordListOne[rand1] + " " + wordListTwo[rand2] + " " + wordListThree[rand3];

        System.out.println("What we need is a " + phrase);
        }
}
```

Error:

> Main.java:1: error: class PhraseOMatic is public, should be declared
>   in a file named PhraseOMatic.java public class PhraseOMatic {        ^
>   1 error

Comment: Just like the error message says: The file name has to match the class name (`PhraseOMatic.java`, not `Main.java`). Rename your file (or the class).

Answer (score 0):

Your file must have the same name as the public class defined within it.

Answer (score 0):

your file name should be public class name, and first declared string array comes without space ex.String[] WordListOne